# Python fails to start a GDAL command

Tags: python, gdal

The error message is as follows:

> python3.exe: No module named gdal2tiles

I downloaded the Osgeo4w installer and through this I installed GDAL\OGR 3.4 and python3-gdal libraries.

This is the command line I'm trying to launch:

`python3 -m gdal2tiles -p mercator -z 0-10 -w none --processes=4 -r near --exclude --xyz -a 0.0 -n C:\myMap.geotiff C:\xyzTiles\ --config GDAL_PAM_ENABLED NO`

If instead I explicit the path for gdal2tiles I get another error:

`C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\Scripts\gdal2tiles -p mercator -z 0-1 -w none --processes=4 -r near --exclude --xyz -a 0.0 -n C:\myMap.geotiff C:\xyzTiles\ --config GDAL_PAM_ENABLED NO`

> AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute '**spec**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the module visible to Python by moving to the scripts folder, inside the cmd file. I don't know if there is a way to set this path globally on the operating system. For now, however, I have solved it like this.

`CD C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\Scripts`

`python3 -m gdal2tiles -p mercator -z 0-10 -w none --processes=4 -r near --exclude --xyz -a 0.0 -n C:\myMap.geotiff C:\xyzTiles\ --config GDAL_PAM_ENABLED NO`